# Give bounty when problem cannot be reproduced

Tags: discussion, answers, bounties

I have a bounty set to a question of myself and someone has given an answer.

However, the problem does not exist anymore (I have restarted the computer which I seldom do and the problem is not showing up anymore).

Since I cannot tell if the solution works and not even if I can use the solution, should I still give the bounty? I upvoted because the answer might be correct and for the time he took to answer.

Comment: It's your bounty to decide whether the poster earned it or whether you want 50% or more of it to just evaporate.

Comment: Is it possible to give a partial bounty?

Comment: My current understanding is that if you don't award the full bounty, 50% of it will be awarded to one or more answers with > 2 upvotes.

Comment: Ok well currently I have one answer which only I upvoted (guess it is not an interesting question though).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the answer doesn't provably solve the problem, then I wouldn't give the bounty.

(Unless it can be proven.)

I would, however, answer your own question, and state that a reboot *did* solve the problem.

Comment: Note that a reboot is probably not the actual solution, it just made the symptom go away temporarily. The problem most likely will return.

Comment: @AaronBertrand True, although without knowing anything about the problem, I personally wouldn't feel comfortable guessing. Especially with MS products.

Comment: It's 'only' a hobby project, so the warning is not critical, however I just don't like having warnings in something I create, even if I'm the only one looking at it. Besides, it distracts from possible real warning (currently I have 0 errors, 0 warnings and 0 messages and I like to keep it that way).